# Float/Double comparison not working in Solar System simulation

Tags: c++, animation, floating-point, sdl-2

I am making a simple game/simulation of the solar system (just the Sun, Earth, and the Moon) using SDL2. I am using a floating point to represent the degrees of Earth relative to the Sun (i.e. 0 deg is east, 90 deg is down apparently, etc.). When I try to lock the value between 0 and 360, it doesn't work.

I currently cap the simulation at 90 fps and want 1 revolution per 60 seconds.

```
// The desired FPS and the number of milliseconds (ticks) between frame draws.
const int FPS = 90;
const int TICKS_PER_FRAME = 1000 / FPS;
// The number of seconds it will take for Earth to make one revolution around the sun.
const int EARTH_REVOLUTION_IN_SECONDS = 1 * 60;
// Number of degrees per millisecond for the Earth.
const float EARTH_DEGREES_PER_MILLISECOND = (float)EARTH_REVOLUTION_IN_SECONDS / 360000.0f;
```

I place the Earth about 1/3 the height of the computer screen away from the Sun, start the Earth at 0.0 degrees, and start a timer.

```
   // The distance from the Sun's center to the Earth's center. This will be 
   // a quarter of the screen height (presumed to be the smaller dimension).
   int distSunToEarth = resolution_y * 0.3;

   // Starting degrees of Earth relative to the Sun. 0.0 degrees is East.
   float earthDegrees = 0.0f;

   // Amount of time between now and the last frame draw.
   Uint32 deltaTime = 0;
   // The start time. No frames have been drawn yet.
   Uint32 startedTime = SDL_GetTicks();
   // Set current time to the started time.
   Uint32 currentTime = startedTime;
```

At the begin of the main loop, I check if the amount of time that has passed is greater than the amount of time that are supposed to be between frames.

```
   // Get the current time in milliseconds.
   currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();
   // Calculate how much time has passed since the last frame draw.
   deltaTime = currentTime - startedTime;

   // If the amount of time that has passed is greater than our desired
   // delay between frames, draw the next frame.
   if (deltaTime > TICKS_PER_FRAME) {
      /* Draw Frame */
   }
```

Here is the logic for drawing and moving the Earth. earthDegrees should stay between 0 and 360, but it doesn't. The code still reports that it is within those values however.

```
   /* Earth */

   // Determine the center of the Earth. Start from the Sun's center and calculate the
   // x and y values relative to it using Soh-Cah-Toa (Yay, trigonometry!). The degrees must
   // be converted to radians using <degrees> * PI / 180.
   int earthCenterX = backgroundCenterX + (distSunToEarth * cos(earthDegrees * M_PI / 180));
   int earthCenterY = backgroundCenterY + (distSunToEarth * sin(earthDegrees * M_PI / 180));

   // Determine the x and y values needed to center the Earth sprite at the above coordinates.
   int earthSpriteX = earthCenterX - (earthSpriteSheet.GetClipWidth() / 2);
   int earthSpriteY = earthCenterY - (earthSpriteSheet.GetClipHeight() / 2);

   // Render the next frame.
   earthSpriteSheet.RenderNextFrame(earthSpriteX, earthSpriteY);

   // Move the Earth aroudn the Sun. Multiply the number of milliseconds that 
   // have passed by the number of degrees the Earth moves per millisecond.
   earthDegrees += ((float)deltaTime * EARTH_DEGREES_PER_MILLISECOND);

   //printf("degrees: %f.\n", (float)deltaTime * EARTH_DEGREES_PER_MILLISECOND);
   //printf("earthDegrees: %f.\n\n", earthDegrees);

   // If the degrees become negative, loop back to 360.
   //
   // e.g. if earthDegrees become -2.5 degrees, the new degrees would be:
   // 360 deg - abs(-2.5 deg) => 357.5 deg.
   if (earthDegrees < 0.0)
   {
       printf("Less than 0.0");
       earthDegrees = 360.0f - abs(earthDegrees);
   }
   // Else if the Earth becomes greater than 2PI, round back to 0.
   //
   // e.g. if degrees become 362.5, the new degrees would be:
   // 362.5 deg - 360 deg => 2.5 deg.
   else if (earthDegrees > 360.0f)
   {
       printf("Greater than 360.0");
       earthDegrees = earthDegrees - 360.0;
   }
   else if (earthDegrees >= 0.0f && earthDegrees <= 360.0f)
   {
       printf("Between 0 and 360\n");
   }

   printf("earthDegrees: %d.\n", earthDegrees);



   /* 
   ...
   Render code 
   ...
   */

   // Reset the started time and current time to now.
   startedTime = SDL_GetTicks();
   currentTime = startedTime;
   // Reset the change in time to 0.
   deltaTime = 0;
```

This is the output of the code. Despite the fact that earthDegrees is not within 0 and 360, the else-if statement that checks if it is between 0 and 360 evaluates to true.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("earthDegrees: %d.\n", earthDegrees);` doesn't print `float` it prints integers.

Try `printf("earthDegrees: %f.\n", earthDegrees);`

Comment: That would appear to be the issue... My earth sprite isn't moving but at least the degrees are changing apparently. Thank you.

Comment: Does this really answer the question?  The question posted doesn't sound like an output formatting issue.  Also, using the incorrect format specifier for `printf` is undefined behavior.  Better to use `std::cout` where you don't get into this trouble.